# One jQuery command for multiple divs of same class

Tags: jquery, html, class

I'm new to jQuery. I'm trying to use one jQuery command to effect multiple divs of the same class:

HTML:

```
<div class="textbox">hi</div>
<div class="textbox">hi</div>
<div class="textbox">hi</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.textbox').focus(function(){
$('.textbox').addClass('newstyle');
});
```

Unfortunately, the JS code effects all three divs with the class "textbox" at the SAME TIME. What I want is for each textbox to react individually.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the .someotherdiv? You have many someotherdivs?

Comment: Consider using a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Sorry Sree, I updated the JS. I don't want all .textbox classes to be effected at the same time by the JS. I want them to happen one by one.

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like this

```
$('.textbox').focus(function(){
    $(this).addClass('newstyle');
});
```

Or you can Also store the element in a variable

```
$('.textbox').focus(function(){
   var element =  this;
   $(element).addClass('newstyle');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correctly using `focus` but need to tell jquery to add the class just to the element that is under `focus`, rather than all elements that match that class.

I've corrected your code by using `$(this)` which tells jquery just to act upon the element in question.

I've also added a bit of jquery for `focusout` so the class is removed when you stop focusing on a given textbox.

I've switched your `div` for `input` to make the example interactive, but the code will work for either case.

```js
$('.textbox').focus(function(){
  $(this).addClass('newstyle');
});

$('.textbox').focusout(function(){
  $(this).removeClass('newstyle');
});
```

```css
.newstyle {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="textbox" value="one">
<input class="textbox" value="two">
<input class="textbox" value="three">
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because in your focus function, you are targetting all divs by class name. The solution is `this`:

```
$('.textbox').focus(function(){
    $(this).addClass('newstyle');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.textbox').focus(function(){
$(this).addClass('newstyle');
});
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.